# Задний фон отображается не там где нужно

Tags: html, css

Хочу поставить particles на фон сайта, но он слезает вниз немогу понять из-за чего? вот код html

```
   <div id="particles-js">
        <div id="wrapper">
            <section class="main">
                <?=$content?>
            </section>
            <section class="additional">
                <?=$right?>
            </section>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/particles.js/2.0.0/particles.min.js" defer></script>
    <script src="<?=ROOT?>js/main.js" defer></script>
```

код css все то ,что относится к этим блокам:

```
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: black;
    font:16px Arial , Helvetica , sans-serif;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
    width: 900px;
    margin: 50px auto 0;
    border: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
    padding: 5px;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Надо добавить `position` или [z-index](http://htmlbook.ru/css/z-index)

```css
html {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

body {
  position: relative; 
  background-color: black;
  font:16px Arial , Helvetica , sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  width: 900px;
  margin: 50px auto 0;
  border: 1px solid #fbfbfb;
  padding: 5px;
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: row nowrap;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо, уже разобрался , не знаю как закрыть вопрос